# Protractor: Need help locating an error message that only is displayed for 3 seconds

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, elementor

I am creating a protractor script, and I need to verify that an error message is displayed on the screen, but the message is only set to be displayed for 3 seconds.

As shown in the screenshot [screenshot of alert - error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Ydg.png) (only appears for 3 seconds), I should be able to simply locate the message through the span tag, but it is not working.

In my typescript code, I have tried the following . css code:

```
private errorMsgRetrieveCards = element(by.css('alerts-component>div:nth-of-type(1)>div>span:nth-of-type(1)'));
```

and the following .xpath code:

```
private errorMsgRetrieveCards = element(by.xpath('/html/body/consumer-component/div/consumer-details-component/div/alerts-component/div/'));
```

In both cases, I am getting the same error message when I run my script in protractor:

```
 Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, alerts-component>div:nth-of-type(1)>div>span:nth-of-type(1))
```

Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, alerts-component>div:nth-of-type(1)>div>span:nth-of-type(1))
        at WebDriverError (/work/paysafe-wab-web-admin-fe/frontend/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Running this beforehand generally fixes the problem for me

`browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath(/html/body/consumer-component/div/consumer-details-component/div/alerts-component/div/'))))`